# My Ruby on rails DELETE function do not work?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is Controller file

```
def destroy
@day = Day.find(params[:id])
@day.destroy

redirect_to days_path
end
```

This is index file

```
<td><%= link_to 'Delete', day_path(day), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

This is application.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

<%= javascript_include_tag 'bootstrap.min.js', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

<%= javascript_include_tag 'default', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

This is application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require ajax_setup
//= require ajax_modal
//= require bootstrap
//= require flash_message
//= require visibility_map
//= require modal
//= require select2
//= require select2_init
```

My Problem is When i SET UP EVERYTHING, there is no error in the terminal, but i can not delete this from database. When I click Delete link, nothing changed, no error. It does not work? Thanks for help!!

Comment: When you click the delete link does the confirmation dialog show?

Comment: No, the dialog did not show. @SunilD.

Comment: Can you show the rest of your index view

Comment: Third Part    <% @days.each do |day| %>
            <tr>
              <td><%= day.id %></td>
              <td><%= day.date %></td>
              <td><%= day.name %></td>
              <td><%= day.column %></td>
              <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_day_path(day) %></td>
              <td><%= link_to 'Delete', day_path(day), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
            </tr>
            <% end %>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: Thanks - I meant in your post so that it's formatted.

Comment: @gwalshington <td><%= link_to 'Delete', day_path(day),                                               method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>                                </td>
            </tr>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `//= require jquery_ujs` in `application.js`.

Check [this](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/a-tour-of-rails-jquery-ujs) out for its explanation.

Comment: Is `//= require jquery_ujs` is already added in your `application.js`?

Comment: YES, my application.js has this code //= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require ajax_setup
//= require ajax_modal
//= require bootstrap
//= require flash_message
//= require visibility_map
//= require modal
//= require select2
//= require select2_init

Comment: In console, did you get any error after clicking `delete` button?

Comment: This is the point, no error, click delete, nothing happen, in my terminal, it just to SELECT. Terminal show after click: Started GET "/days/19" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-13 19:14:33 +0000
Processing by CpController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"19"}
  Day Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "days".* FROM "days" WHERE "days"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 19]]
  Day Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "days".* FROM "days"
  Rendered cp/index.html.erb within layouts/cp_layout (6.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 29ms (Views: 24.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)

Comment: Your `DELETE` request gets converted into `GET`. Have you included `application.js` in your view?

Comment: Yeah, i think so, in my index file, code is <td><%= link_to 'Delete', day_path(day), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>.In my file app/assets/javascripts/application.js

Comment: You must be sure. Check in your `layout` or html view that you've included  `application.js`. If you're not sure try adding `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>` in `<head>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try

`<td><%= link_to 'Delete', day, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>`

```
def destroy
    @day.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to days_url, notice: 'Day was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

Comment: Just to cover all the bases - are you restarting your server each time you try these adjustments? And you've definitely migrated the db?

Comment: I think i got this  work, My application did got this javascript code, but the lay out i Use is not application.html.erb, so actually i DID NOT include this code in actual layout.html.erb. i JUST FORGET THAT, and stuck......Sorry ...Thanks you very much for helping me on this....

Comment: No worries - glad to try to help!